# access Denied during File Upload with OneDrive (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm am currently trying to **upload** back my file to **OneDrive**.

I have been following OneDrive Graph [**docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) and Tanaike's [**example**](https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/08/15/uploading-files-to-onedrive-using-node.js/).

I am able to **create an upload session** but when I try to **Upload bytes to the upload session** I get

```
function uploadFile(uploadUrl, context) { // Here, it uploads the file by every chunk.
    asy.eachSeries(getparams(), function(st, callback){
        setTimeout(function() {
            fs.readFile(file, function read(e, f) {
                context.log(st.cr);
                //context.log(st.clen);
                request.put({
                    url: uploadUrl,
                    headers: {
                        //'Content-Length': st.clen,
                        'Content-Range': st.cr,
                    },
                    body: f.slice(st.bstart, st.bend + 1),
                }, function(er, re, bo) {
                    if(er){
                        context.log('   Upload Error' + bo);
                    }
                    else{
                        context.log('   ERROR HERE: ' + bo);
                        context.res = {
                            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
                            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},  
                            body: bo
                        };
                    }
                });
            });
            callback();
        }, st.stime);
    });
}
```

**Response from PUT Request:**

```
"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"The caller does not have permission to perform the action."}
```

I've checked and am sure I am the owner of the folder.
I did alot of googling but I just unable to find how I am getting denied.

I tried it on **Postman** too, with the same error. 
I left Authorization Header field out, and

**Header**

```
Content-Range:bytes 0-4019880/4019881
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Anyone who tried this before can kindly guide me?

Comment: Check your API permissions. This specific function requires _Files.ReadWrite_ and _Files.ReadWrite.All_ permissions for a personal Microsoft account

Comment: Can you confirm that you are including the bearer token and both the `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` in the PUT header? Also, it isn't clear from your code, but when you split the file it must be in `327,680` byte increments: "Using a fragment size that does not divide evenly by 320 KiB will result in errors committing some files".